# Mysql Sorting and display it in html table

Tags: mysql

I've a table with data in mysql as below;

[image]

is it possible to make it to display in HTML table as below?

[image]

Comment: There is a typo in your example tables you gave above.  Group A should have: 1 23 23-A-test1 and 2 23 23-A-QQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query you can try using:

```
SELECT CONCAT(tb_poupload.tid, ' ', tb_poupload.invno, ' ', tb_poupload.filename)
AS grouplabel,
SUBSTRING(tb_poupload.filename, 4, 1) AS groupname
FROM tb_poupload
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(tb_poupload.filename, 4, 1)
```

This should give you the following result set:

```
-------------------------------
|   grouplabel    | groupname |
-------------------------------
| 1 23 23-A-test1 |     A     |
| 2 23 23-A-QQ    |     A     |
| 4 23 23-B-PMN   |     B     |
| 3 23 23-C-M87   |     C     |
| 5 23 23-C-KIM   |     C     |
-------------------------------
```

As for rendering this result set in an HTML table, that is an entirely different answer.  If you were running a simple Java web application, you could iterate over this set by `group` and create a JSP page which looks something like the screen capture in your question.

Comment: I got this error from mysql #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group FROM tb_poupload ORDER BY group' at line 1

Comment: I had a mistake in my query where I was reusing an ALIAS inside the same query in which it was defined.  I corrected it and now the query should be fine.

Comment: I still got the same error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group FROM tb_poupload ORDER BY SUBSTRING(tb_poupload.filename, 4, 1)' at line 1?

Comment: Oops...the word `group` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.  Try the new query and let me know if it works now.

Comment: can you please teach me how do i display it in HTML table by using PHP?

Comment: Can you create a new question called "rendering MySQL table in PHP" in which you preface the question with the working query you already have?  This is really too big to add to the current question.